# The Contradiction in Soy Production: Livestock Feed versus Human Consumption?

Tags: ecology

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this ecological question. I apologize for any inconvenience, and please let me know if it is.

There is a contradiction regarding soy production and its effects on the environment:

1. According to [Our World in Data](https://ourworldindata.org/drivers-of-deforestation#more-than-three-quarters-of-global-soy-is-fed-to-animals), more than three-quarters (77%) of global soy is used as feed for livestock, primarily for meat and dairy production. This means that only about one-fifth (23%) of soy is used for direct human consumption or other purposes.

[image]

2. The article also mentions that only 7% of soybeans are directly fed to livestock, while the remaining 70% is processed into soy cake, which is used as livestock feed. Soy cake is a by-product of soybean oil extraction and is classified based on its crude protein content.

Now, the question arises: what happens to the extracted soybean oil? Is it not used for human consumption? If it is used for human consumption, then humans are also directly responsible for 70% of soy consumption. Additionally, direct human consumption (including food and industrial uses) accounts for more than 24% of soy consumption.